# How to pass a variable sized array to TensorFlow Lite model

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, accelerometer, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to find how I can pass a dynamic-sized array (not fixed size) into my TensorFlow.

I am building an Android App to read Accelerometer values and predict an activity. I have built a TensorFlow model and am able to successfully import `.tflite` file into my Android.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# save the model
with open("model-v2.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

In my case, the number of Accelerometer X, Y, Z values I would be passing to my TensorFlow model will vary each time. I could pass a series of 10 values or 100 values. So I am trying to find how I can make the TensorFlow model accept a dynamic-sized array instead of a fixed size.

I am new to TensorFlow. So is this something that can be easily achieved?

Comment: To my knowledge you are restricted to fixed inputs and outputs with Tensorflow. Similar: [How to train with inputs of variable size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46179973/295004) If you are doing over-time data, look at how audio processing is handled, or [text processing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are following [the latest steps to use TFLite as of 2023](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/on_device_training/overview), you would be able to achieve somewhat dynamic behaviors using [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) by setting a [TensorShape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) with some `None`s in it. An example from the steps mentioned above:

```py
  @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec([None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE], tf.float32),
  ])
  def infer(self, x):
```